# javapos: how to set font size?

Tags: javapos

I'm using javapos 1.15 to print on some epson thermal printer.
All basics feats works properly except one: I don't know how to change the font size (neither type, but that's ok).
According to documentation I could use some escaped caractere but none works. I can make text wider
and bolder but not smaller.

Any help here?

So basically

> mPrinter.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT,ESC+"|bC hello"); //That's works
> mPrinter.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT,ESC+"|50P hello"); //doesn't works

Thanks in advance

(fyi I print on epson TM-m30 that allow all text size (works fine with and AndroidEpsonSDK))

Answer (score 0):

To change the font size (decrease), you need to change the `RecLineChars` property.
Only the values contained in the `RecLineCharsList` property can be specified for the `RecLineChars` property.

It cannot normally be specified in the middle of a `PrintNormal` print request string.
It may be possible to support it as a vendor-specific feature, but even in that case, it is only possible to change line units, and it is not possible to change only the middle of a line.